# Removing the first word after " not"

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
s = "grocery store not liquor shop not restaurant, sell milk"
```

, and I would like to remove the first word after "not". How can I implement it in python? I am looking for results like:

```
"grocery store shop, sell milk"
```

or

```
"grocery store, sell milk"
```

if removing all words between 'not' and any punctuation/end of string is possible too.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Have you tried a loop?

Comment: Why do you have 2 possible output? Isn't the first result the only possible one? In the second result. the word shop disappeared.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am looking for regex approach

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix yeah the first one is the possible one, but my final goal is to remove words between not and any symbol/end of the string, which is difficult to achieve

Comment: @Chiefscreation What do you mean by "any symbol?" Punctuation?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes that's right

Comment: @Chiefscreation. I made an answer that works with the punctuation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import re
s = "grocery store not liquor shop not restaurant, sell milk"

print (re.sub(r'\s+not \w+', '', s))
```

You'll get this:

```
grocery store shop, sell milk
```

Comment: Output : `grocery store shop, sell milk` :)

Comment: That also mangles words that end in `not`, e.g. `snot salad` becomes just `s`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. To be fair, you would generally prefer a plate of plaind old s to a plate of snot salad.

Comment: New version won't work if sentence starts with `not`. I think you want `\b\s*not`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You don't like snot salad?! Also, your suggestion fails with input like `The forget-me-not is a type of flower` (I wouldn't use `\b` with free-form English text). Better would be `(?:^|\s+)not` (plus one or more trailing spaces, maybe optional, but it's unclear whether the OP would want to delete a single `not` at the end of the text)

Comment: `The forget-me- a type of flower` almost works. At least not as bad as it could be. I didn't know you could use `^` in a non-capture group like that

Comment: I am going to leave the answer as it stands now, though comments by @MadPhysicist and others are technically correct.  Taking into consideration the apparent technical sophistication of the [person asking the] question further refinement of the regex would only detract from clarity of the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove characters up to the next punctuation or end-of-line, try this:

```
s = "grocery store not liquor shop not restaurant, sell milk"
re.sub(r'\b\s*not\s+[\w\s]+', '', s)
```

results in

```
'grocery store, sell milk'
```

Basically, remove any strings that start with "not", followed by space, followed by all the available non-(word or space) characters, i.e., punctuation. If you want to get rid of the trailing comma too, try this modification:

```
s = "grocery store not liquor shop not restaurant, sell milk"
re.sub(r'\b\s*not\s+[\w\s]+[^\w\s]?', '', s)
```

The trailing `?` ensures that the end-of-line is matched as well as actual punctation.

These expressions work correctly for extreme cases like

```
not milk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use re you can always use a loop.

```
def remove_after(string, kwrd):
    s = string.split(' ')
    new = []
    skip = []
    for i,v in enumerate(s):
        if v != kwrd:
            if i not in skip:
                new.append(v)
        else:
            skip.append(i+1)
    return ' '.join(new)

print(remove_after("grocery store not liquor shop not restaurant, sell milk", 'not'))
```

Comment: OP explicitly wants re.